# Another phrase for "the texts are a microcosm for marxism"

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

I hope everyone is doing well. I'm currently trying to write something but I've got a bit of a writer's block lol. Could someone help me rephrase this into a more concise and smoother sentence:

"The texts are a microcosm for marxism"

The idea that I am trying to convey is that the texts are a metaphor for marxism. I would like to sound concise but also sophisticated but not too sure what to say :(

Comment: From such a short quote and explanation it's difficult to understand quite what you're after. Could you expand a little on the theme, please?

Comment: My apologies BoldBen. I'm writing an essay about two texts and I want to convey the message that these texts are unified by the ideologies of marxism. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I mean it sounds concise but I want to make it sound a bit sophisticated... not too sure why but it's just an urge inside me haha

Comment: What's wrong with your own expression **"these texts are unified by the ideologies of marxism"** which is your own sentence. Alternatively you could say something like "Both texts fully express Marxist ideology". I don"t think that you've used 'microcosm' correctly in your question, 'a microcosm' is something which is a small but complete representation of something else. For instance "Politically the market town is a microcosm of the state" (not necessarily true but the best example I can think of at the moment)